# Why speed of Mangalyan is constant?

Tags: kinematics, rocket-science

I have learned in school regarding the relationship between speed,acceleration and distance is

$$v^2-u^2=2as $$

The initial velocity of India's Mars Orbiter Mission, MOM, is 32 km/s [source](http://indiatoday.intoday.in/story/mars-orbiter-mission-india-leaves-earth-orbit-isro-china/1/327296.html) and now the speed of MOM is 34.99 km/s [source](http://indiatoday.intoday.in/story/mars-orbiter-mission-india-leaves-earth-orbit-isro-china/1/327296.html)

If we assume the acceleration is constant and put the values in the above formula then the final speed is never 34.99 km/s.

So I wanted to know why MOM does not follow the above rule.

Answer (score 1):

Your example is derived for the special case where the acceleration has constant magnitude and constant direction. But the force on an object in a non-circular orbit is not constant, but depends on the distance between the orbiter and the planet.

Comment: sorry did not understand,can you please describe in detail